# Why does SQL Server CE Count() return a negative value?

Tags: c#, sql, webmatrix

I'm using SQL Server CE so I can't use conditional statements. I'm trying to check if a record exists, then if it does, update it, and if it doesn't, create it.

I printed out the value for check and it was -1.

```
var db = Database.Open("DB2");

var check = "SELECT count(*) FROM QuestionnaireData WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

if (db.Execute(check) == 0)
{
    var insert = "INSERT INTO QuestionnaireData VALUES (@0, @1)";
    db.Execute(insert, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, "TEST");
}
else {
    var update = "UPDATE QuestionnaireData SET Q1='" + "TEST" + "' WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    db.Execute(update);
};
```

Comment: Where is the code that prints the value?

Comment: I included it just below all of that. It was just <p>@check;</p>

Comment: Are you certain the `Execute` method returns the count? normally I would expect that would return the success result or a recordset. Certainly the ADO Execute method returns a recordset, not an integer

Comment: I'm not actually, that's a good question.

Comment: as an aside, another approach might be to perform the UPDATE first, and if the number of rows affected returns 0, then perform the INSERT.

Comment: Yes, you could utilise `@@ROWCOUNT` for this. I believe the OP already has another question on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intellisense for `Execute()` reports:

> Executes a non-query SQL statement.

Since you actually are querying for data, you want one of the `Query()` methods.

And since you only want a single value (the count), use `QueryValue()`:

> Executes a SQL query that returns a single scalar value as the result.

Try this instead:

```
var count = Convert.ToInt32(db.QueryValue(check));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return the data though? I see what you mean, it would probably work, I would just check if it's null or not, it just seems sloppier.

Comment: Oh okay, I gotcha. You're right, it will always be an int. Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I tried that and it broke, it says there's no definition for ExecuteScalar

Comment: WebMatrix.Data.Database

Comment: Looks like `QueryValue` is the equivalent. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Why they went and created _another_ library with half matching methods and half not I don't understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Webmatrix` is much newer than `ADO` though I'm not exactly sure of it's purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I have rewrited your code with more attention to the syntax of the Webmatrix.Data library

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("DB2");

    var check = "SELECT * FROM QuestionnaireData WHERE Id = @0";
    var questionnaire = db.Query(check, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

    if (questionnaire.Any())
    {
        var update = "UPDATE QuestionnaireData SET Q1 = 'TEST' WHERE ID = @0";
        db.Execute(update, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    }
    else {
        var insert = "INSERT INTO QuestionnaireData (Id, Q1) VALUES (@0, @1)";
        db.Execute(insert, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, "TEST");
    }
}
```

I hope it could help.